# Rewriting SCSS to LESS

Tags: css, sass, less

Just started learning about LESS and it seems very similar to SCSS (SCSS = $ & LESS = @).

HOWEVER, I can't seem to get LESS to work after rewriting it from SCSS.

I suspect it has to do with my loop. Is it the way I phrase my loop or the percentage equation?

---

### SCSS

```
body{
    background:black;
    font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}

.glitch{
    color:white;
    font-size:100px;
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    &:before, &:after{
        content:attr(data-text);
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        color:white;
        background:black;
        overflow:hidden;
        clip:rect(0,900px,0,0); 
    }
    &:before{
        left:-2px;
        text-shadow:-5px 0 red;
        animation:noise-anim 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
    }
    &:after{
        left: 2px;
        text-shadow: -5px 0 blue;
        animation: noise-anim 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
    }
}
@keyframes noise-anim{
    $steps:20;
    @for $i from 0 through $steps{
        #{percentage($i*(1/$steps))}{
          clip:rect(random(100)+px,9999px,random(100)+px,0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

### LESS

### https://codepen.io/kangpeter5/pen/mMOyOq

```
body {
    background:black;
    font-family: "Varela", sans-serif;
}

.glitch {
    color:white;
    font-size:100px;
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    &:before, &:after{
        content:attr(data-text);
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        color:white;
        background:black;
        overflow:hidden;
        clip:rect(0,900px,0,0); 
    }
    &:before{
        left:-2px;
        text-shadow: -3px 0 red;
        animation:noise-anim 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
    }
    &:after{
        left: 2px;
        text-shadow: -3px 0 blue;
        animation: noise-anim 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
    }
}
@keyframes noise-anim{
    @steps:20;
    .loop(@steps, @i:0) when (@i<=@steps){
        @keyframeSel: percentage(@i*(1/@steps));
        @{keyframeSel}{
            clip:rect(random(100)+px, 9999px, random(100)+px,0);
        }
        .loop(@steps, (@i+1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several errors in your less file, but I must assure you all could be resolved only if you were red documentation carefully ;) As I don't understand why you are about to switch from scss to less even though I prefer less anyway, they both do same things even though either have different advantages and disadvantages, still I'd like to help you and will explain what is wrong with your code on codepen.

So first of all, I have checked your compiled code and saw that there were no output from your loop at all, so first thing I did - just added first execution to start loop somewhere, because it was declared, but not started. Then I saw you are using `random(100)` mixin that does not exist in less, so just mocked that up, put out to variables and seems like it is working now :)

```
@keyframes noise-anim{
  @steps:20;
  .loop(@steps, @i:0) when (@i=<@steps){
    @keyframeSel: percentage(@i*(1/@steps),~'%');
    @{keyframeSel}{
      @rand1: ~"`Math.random()*100`px";
      @rand2: ~"`Math.random()*100`px";
      clip:rect(@rand1, 9999px, @rand2,0);
    }
    .loop(@steps, (@i+1));
  }
  .loop(@steps);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Maciej. I recently got a new gig where they use LESS (I was slightly familiar with SCSS before).